# execute function every x seconds in flash as3?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the following code to check for updates in mysql database using flash as3 (actionscript 3.0).

The code will check the database using PHP on my server and will display the details in Flash application.

The issue that I have is that I am trying to run this code every 8 seconds but when I run the code and I `trace(urlRequest);` I get 100's of traces in less than 20 seconds!

I thought giving a `setInterval(checkDataBase, 8000);` will sort this issue out and will run the code every 8 seconds but I have no luck with this!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

This is my code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkForNewOrder);
function checkForNewOrder (e:Event):void 
{
    checkDataBase();
}

/*
function we use to send the form
*/
function checkDataBase ():void 
{
    /*
    we use the URLVariables class to store our php variables 
    */
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    phpVars.result_textL = result_textL.text;

    /*
    we use the URLRequest method to get the address of our php file and attach the php vars.
    */
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/checkOrder.php");

    trace(urlRequest);  

    /*
    the POST method is used here so we can use php's $_POST function in order to recieve our php variables.
    */
    urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    /*
    this attaches our php variables to the url request
    */
    urlRequest.data = phpVars;      

    /*
    we use the URLLoader class to send the request URLVariables to the php file
    */
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    /*
    runs the function once the php file has spoken to flash
    */
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

    /*
    we send the request to the php file
    */
    urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

}

setInterval(checkDataBase, 8000);

/*
function to show result
*/
function showResult (e:Event):void 
{
    orderDetails.text = "" + e.target.data.result_message;

    if(orderDetails.text != "")
    {
        rejectBtn.y = 380.20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the Timer class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkForNewOrder);
```

This causes your function to be called with the framerate you set up, so mabye 30 times per second.

setIntervall will add additional calls to the function. It does not override the enter frame.

Get rid of the enter frame register and you should be good to go.